# Using <cfmail> with a from attributes that has invalid email account

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfmail

I want to send an email from error@domain.com to the debugging team debug@domain.com using this simple code

```
<cfmail to="debug@domain.com" from="error@domain.com" 
 subject="sending error message plz respond!" 
 username="sender@domain.com" password="password-correct" 
 server="mail.domain.com" type="html">
      bla bla bla bla blga    
</cfmail>
```

The issue is if the "from" email address is not an existing email account I get a verification error on mail log of ColdFusion although the username is correct. This used to work in cf8, did they now change it?

Answer (score 5):

Has nothing to do with CF and is likely your smtp server.  Are you using gmail?

Comment: Why do you not want to use a valid email address in the from attribute?

Comment: if i want to create more teams i dont want to create more emails accounts for no reason... if i change hosting provider i will have to create all those accounts again...

Comment: Write a script to create the email accounts.